# How to review the init script output on a dedicated server?

Tags: debian, dedicated-server, init

I have rented a dedicated server, running Debian stable. Is the startup output that you would see on the screen (if you had one) stored anywhere? If not, is there a non-intrusive way to make that data available after the next reboot? Or how else do you make sure that the system boots up cleanly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

enable bootlogd, which is part of sysvinit-utils by setting `BOOTLOGD_ENABLE=Yes` in `/etc/default/bootlogd` which will log in `/var/log/boot`.  In wheezy and beyond bootlogd is in its own package and will not have `/etc/default/bootlogd`